# lincom Stata command implementation in R for coefficients from multiple equations

Tags: regression-coefficients, multiple-comparisons

I am facing a problem in comparing the coefficients from two separate regression equations. I can't use SUR (Seemingly unrelated regression) framework here. By that, I am especially talking about infeasibility of systemfit command in R. The reason is that it takes input from objects that come from **lm** command. I am using **feols** in my case. Here systemfit is telling me that it doesn't know how to read the output of feols regression command. feols is required for me since dataset is quite big and lm command is taking too much time without giving output result.

I am having the two following regression equations:
$$  y_{it} = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 x_{it} + \varepsilon_{it} ... (1)\\ 
 y_{it} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 z_{it} + \varepsilon_{it} ... (2)$$
The difference between these two equations is that (1) is about year T and (2) is about year T+1. One can consider that $z_{it} = x_{it} + x'_{it}$. So if it can be shown statistically that $\beta_1 - \alpha_1 \neq 0$, then we can claim that z has a different impact than x on y. Also, it is not possible to separately include $x'_{it}$ in equation (2).

I have come to know that **lincom** command in Stata allows testing of linear combination of coefficients. There is a way to perform similar tests in R but only for coefficients of a single model, https://rpubs.com/djcava/lincom . However, I have two models (from equations 1 and 2).